# Import maven plugin configuration by composition rather than inheritance. Can it be done with build extensions?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-extension

Import maven plugin configuration by composition rather than inheritance. Can it be done with build extensions?

I have used maven for more than 3 years and there's one shortcoming that has always bugged me.
It's time to find a solution for that already.

The problem:

I have a "daddy" maven module with 3 children: "boy", "girl", and "kid".
Each of these children must have its own distinct set of plugin configurations for a default "clean install" build.
I don't want to put that configuration on the children's poms. I'd rather put it somewhere that I can reuse later.

I have tried using profiles for that, and it doesn't work - please see my comment and attached project on [MNG-5127](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5127)

I have found a better solution by making the following changes on the [daddy.zip](http://jira.codehaus.org/secure/attachment/60738/daddy.zip) project:

1) On daddy's pom, Replaced the [profiles] with plugin executions having [phase]none[/phase]

```
<build>
    ...
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>printboy</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <echo message="@@@@@@@@@@@@ HELLO! Iam a BOY project"/>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>printkid</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <echo message="@@@@@@@@@@@@ HELLO! Iam a KID project"/>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>printgirl</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <echo message="@@@@@@@@@@@@ HELLO! Iam a GIRL project"/>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
</build>
```

2) On the same pom, added a custom build extension

```
<build>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>br.com.touchtec.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>execution-enabler-extension</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
    ...
</build>
```

3) The extension will change the plugin execution phases based on the project's property values. Java code below.

```
@Component(role = AbstractMavenLifecycleParticipant.class, hint = "enableif")
public class EnableIfExtension extends AbstractMavenLifecycleParticipant {

    @Override
    public void afterProjectsRead(MavenSession session)
            throws MavenExecutionException {
        String phase = "validate";
        for(MavenProject project : session.getProjects()){
            Properties properties = project.getProperties();
            if(properties != null){
                if("boy".equals(properties.getProperty("project_type"))){
                    setExecutionPhase(project, "printboy", phase);
                    setExecutionPhase(project, "printkid", phase);
                }
                if("girl".equals(properties.getProperty("project_type"))){
                    setExecutionPhase(project, "printgirl", phase);
                    setExecutionPhase(project, "printkid", phase);
                }
                if("kid".equals(properties.getProperty("project_type"))){
                    setExecutionPhase(project, "printkid", phase);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void setExecutionPhase(MavenProject project, String executionId, String phase) {
        for(Plugin plugin : project.getBuild().getPlugins()){
            if(plugin.getExecutions() != null){
                for(PluginExecution execution : plugin.getExecutions()){
                    if(executionId.equals(execution.getId())){
                        execution.setPhase(phase);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

4) The child module poms only need to define a property that will tell the build extension what to do, for example, the boy project:

```
<project>
    <properties>
        <project_type>boy</project_type>
    </properties>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.family</groupId>
    <artifactId>boy</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.family</groupId>
        <artifactId>daddy</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <!-- No "build" section. Beautifull. -->
</project>
```

Invoking mvn clean install on the daddy project like thiss, will output the desired result: boys will be boys, girls will be girls and both will be kids.

The question is: can we do better?

In theory, a build extension could import the build configuration definitions for boy, girl, and kid from different poms... right?
That would be the a clever and elegant way of importing [build] configuration into a pom.

There are a lot of available maven plugins, but I don't see a lot (actually any) of available build extensions that one can plug into a build.
Does anyone know of a build extension that helps with this?

---

Update

This is not an actual answer, but it's an actual solution to my problem, so here goes.

> Import maven plugin configuration by composition rather than inheritance. Can it be done with build extensions?

Probably

> Does anyone know of a build extension that helps with this?

I'm pretty sure there isn't one

However, there is a solution using profiles.

The trick is that **file-based profile activation is actually inherited** (it only works with maven3 though)

Please see the [daddy2.zip](http://jira.codehaus.org/secure/attachment/60790/daddy2.zip) attached to [MNG-5127](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5127)

This is way better than using the build extension strategy, because using a profile provides more flexibility than just changing a few plugin execution phases.

---

Update 2

> > Does anyone know of a build extension that helps with this?
>
> I'm pretty sure there isn't one

Actually there is something!

It's attached as project in [MNG-5102](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5102) (by Maurizio Pillitu)
I haven't tested it, but it seems it does something very close to the proposed build extension.

Comment: No answer so far, that's worrysome... At least it's good to know [I'm not alone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245621/how-to-inherit-from-a-multimodule-maven-project-with-all-its-goodies).

Comment: A wish in [Maven 3.1](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG/fixforversion/15565#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3Aversion-issues-panel) is to include "mixins" (http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5102).  Sounds a lot like what you're looking for. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be much going on for Maven 3.1; the issues list looks about the same as it did when I looked over a year ago.  :-(

Comment: Yes indeed. I would love if [FreedomSponsors](http://www.freedomsponsors.org/) could help improve that :-)

Comment: I really had lost hope to get an actual answer on this question. But apparently, there is on in the making! THIS IS AWESOME! --> https://twitter.com/maoo/status/230704704668192768

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that [Maven Tiles](https://github.com/repaint-io/maven-tiles) can help you with your specific use-case.
It is still work in progress, but it currently accomplishes what you're describing, I managed to "decompose" the [wicket-quickstart](http://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html) and run Jetty successfully, even adding a multi-module structure.

Any comment or hint is more than welcome.
Thanks,
  Maurizio

Comment: Now that 0.8-beta-6 is out, I added a [daddy3.zip](http://jira.codehaus.org/secure/attachment/61530/daddy3.zip) file to [MNG-5102](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5102?focusedCommentId=310175#comment-310175) that demonstrates how to use it.

Comment: Stable 2.8 as of April 2016

Comment: Why does `<dependencies>` can not be added to a tile and how to import dependency configuration? (The error says: Tile includes dependencies - this will prevent consumers from adding exclusions, use composites instead.)