# How to reuse Maven configuration XML fragments in other configurations

Tags: java, xml, maven

I have dozens of similar but not identical plugin execution configurations. I'd like to re-use parts of them.

The part that I'd like to re-use might look like this:

```xml
<reuseMe>
  <lotsOfXML/>
</reuseMe>
```

Now, some plugin configurations might not contain the above:

```xml
<configuration>
  <simpleStuff/>
</configuration>
```

But other plugin configurations might:

```xml
<configuration>
  <simpleStuff/>
  <complexStuff>
    <reuseMe>
      <lotsOfXML/>
    </reuseMe>
  </complexStuff>
</configuration>
```

Instead of copy pasting that fragment, which is always the same, I'd like some mechanism where I can declare reusable XML fragments, and then just "import" them:

```xml
<configuration>
  <simpleStuff/>
  <complexStuff>
    <reuseMe import="whatever"/>
  </complexStuff>
</configuration>
```

Short of XSL transforming my `pom.xml` files in a preprocessing step, is there any out-of-the-box way this can be done with vanilla Maven? Using `<pluginManagement/>` doesn't seem to work because that would define the `<reuseMe/>` content for all plugin executions as a default, not just for those that need this.

Comment: Not perfect, but you could use the approach described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16540808/can-i-configure-multiple-plugin-executions-in-pluginmanagement-and-choose-from

Comment: @sparty02: Nope, I don't think that's it. That picks up complete plugin execution configurations, but I'd like to copy only XML fragments.

Comment: The general part of the configuration could/should be put into a appropriate parent between (`<plugin>..<configuration>..</configuration></plugin>`) the specialized parts should be put into the appropriate modules related to the `<executions><executions>` and furthermore you can use things `<items combine.children="append">`...  see https://maven.apache.org/pom.html or you can overwrite the configuration via `<configuration combine.childre="override">`... the default is `<configuration combine.childre="merge">`....a realy import is not possible...

Comment: One way of composing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558475/maven-import-plugins-configuration-from-one-project-to-another-using-maven-til

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a JIRA for what you're requesting: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5102

Opened almost 10 years ago, still not solved.

As far as I know, the only out-of-the-box Maven approach involves [plugin executions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16544702/944849).

Otherwise, it's roll your own.

P.S. Not a Maven committer; maybe one of them will see this and we'll both learn something today.